# Redirecting to a different directory with htaccess without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to add some htaccess so that when a visitor goes to:

```
domain.com/xxx
```

They would see the content (without the URL changing) from

```
domain.com/yyy/zzz
```

Also any subcontent would show... like visiting

```
domain.com/xxx/inner-page
```

would show the content from:

```
domain.com/yyy/zzz/inner-page
```

I know that can be done, I just haven't figured out the htaccess code for it yet.

Here's the extra part I'm not sure can be done- sometimes those pages may have full URL links pointing to "/yyy/zzz/inner-page"

I would want anyone going to one of those pages to be redirected (changing the URL) to the equivalent "xxx" url... hopefully without causing a loop of too many redirects issue.  Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^xxx(/.*)?$ yyy/zzz$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Looks like that should work for the first part, but it just gives a 404.

Comment: Are you using some CMS framework like WP, Joomla, CI etc?